# Applying multiple value thresholds to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a data frame in python. I want to apply a threshold to the data. I want all S4 values >0.6 and <1. Please advice on how I could implement this and isolate all threshold entries. Please take into consideration that some of the data entries have a blank S4 value ie the data frame contains blank entries.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you currently have.

Comment: line 1: temp_data = data[data['Total_S4_Sig1'] >0.6]
line 2: dict[key] = temp_data[temp_data['Total_S4_Sig1'] < 1]

where data is the data frame in question. This is screwing me just because of the blank entries.

Comment: @M.Spiller  Running the code mentioned in the above comment gives me the following error.

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: can you post the output of  df.to_dict() ? (where df is your dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to replace the empty strings with `0` first. Then you can handle it the way you have started:

```
data[data['Total_S4_Sig1'] == ""] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```py
data[(data['Total_S4_Sig1'] > 0.6) & (data['Total_S4_Sig1'] < 1.0)]
```

However, I believe the column 'Total_S4_Sig1' is in `str`. You would need to convert it to `float` for the above command to work. To do that:

```py
data['Total_S4_Sig1'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Total_S4_Sig1'], errors='coerce')
```

The above command will convert blanks to `NaN` as well.

Comment: @chintanthakrar - Let me know if this worked for you.